How can I force a WINDOW function in MySQL to show 'NULL' unless complete window frame is available?
I want to get moving sum and moving average on each date for last 7 days (including current day). I used WINDOW function and used ROWS BETWEEN to frame the function which calculates correctly, but it shows sum and avg for even the first date. I want to enforce my query to show 'NULL' unless complete frame of 7 days is available.
Following is table, my query, output, and expected output.
Customer Table:
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,
    visited_on DATE NOT NULL,
    amount DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Customer (customer_id, visited_on, amount) VALUES
(1, '2019-01-01', 100.00),
(2, '2019-01-02', 110.00),
(3, '2019-01-03', 120.00),
(4, '2019-01-04', 130.00),
(5, '2019-01-05', 110.00),
(6, '2019-01-06', 140.00),
(7, '2019-01-07', 150.00),
(8, '2019-01-08', 80.00),
(9, '2019-01-09', 110.00),
(1, '2019-01-10', 130.00),
(3, '2019-01-10', 150.00);


MySQL query:
WITH DAILY_REVENUE AS
    (SELECT
         visited_on,
         SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM
        Customer
    GROUP BY
        visited_on
    ORDER BY
        visited_on ASC
)  -- SELECT * FROM DAILY_REVENUE

, MOVING_AVG AS(
    SELECT
        visited_on,
        SUM(amount) OVER(ORDER BY visited_on ASC
                        ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING
                        AND
                        CURRENT ROW) AS amount,
        CAST(AVG(amount) OVER(ORDER BY visited_on ASC
                        ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING
                        AND
                        CURRENT ROW) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS average_amount
    FROM
        DAILY_REVENUE
        
)   SELECT * FROM MOVING_AVG

Output:



visited_on
amount
average_amount




2019-01-01
100
100


2019-01-02
210
105


2019-01-03
330
110


2019-01-04
460
115


2019-01-05
570
114


2019-01-06
710
118.33


2019-01-07
860
122.86


2019-01-08
840
120


2019-01-09
840
120


2019-01-10
1000
142.86



Expected Output:



visited_on
amount
average_amount




2019-01-01
NULL
NULL


2019-01-02
NULL
NULL


2019-01-03
NULL
NULL


2019-01-04
NULL
NULL


2019-01-05
NULL
NULL


2019-01-06
NULL
NULL


2019-01-07
860
122.86


2019-01-08
840
120


2019-01-09
840
120


2019-01-10
1000
142.86




You can just do a windowed running count and check that it's >= 7.
You can also simplify this by using the named WINDOW clause and shortening it to just ROWS 6 PRECEDING.
WITH DAILY_REVENUE AS (
    SELECT
         visited_on,
         SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM
        Customer
    GROUP BY
        visited_on
)  -- SELECT * FROM DAILY_REVENUE

, MOVING_AVG AS (
    SELECT
        visited_on,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER w >= 7
             THEN SUM(amount) OVER w
          END AS amount,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER w >= 7
             THEN CAST(AVG(amount) OVER w AS DECIMAL(5,2))
          END AS average_amount
    FROM
        DAILY_REVENUE
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY visited_on ROWS 6 PRECEDING)
)
SELECT *
FROM MOVING_AVG
ORDER BY
    visited_on ASC;

db<>fiddle

This works! and thank you for optimizing the query as well. However I am still curious if there is a way within a WINDOW function to enforce such condition without using CASE or is this the only way to enforce NULL using WINDOW function?

No don't think so.

You can also use a self-join so that for each row(the current day), we only join it with dates that are within the last 7 days.
Fiddle
WITH daily_totals AS (
    SELECT 
        visited_on,
        SUM(amount) AS total_amount
    FROM Customer
    GROUP BY visited_on
)

SELECT
    a.visited_on,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(b.visited_on) = 7 THEN SUM(b.total_amount)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS amount,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(b.visited_on) = 7 THEN ROUND(AVG(b.total_amount), 2)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS average_amount
FROM daily_totals a
LEFT JOIN daily_totals b
    ON b.visited_on BETWEEN a.visited_on - INTERVAL 6 DAY AND a.visited_on
GROUP BY a.visited_on
ORDER BY a.visited_on;

Output


That's almost certainly less efficient than using window functions.
